# React Router with Apache2 + PHP7 + MariaDB docker

Tags: apache, docker, xampp, docker-compose, react-router

I'm using Router for React app. When I use it with XAMPP and configure a .htaccess file, the router works fine.
This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Then I decide to create a docker for my app runs in it. I use php7.3.1-apache and mariadb images. This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
 services: 
  php-apache:
  build:
   context: ./php-apache
  ports:
   - 3000:80
  volumes:
   - ./dist:/var/www/html
  links:
   - 'mariadb'

  mariadb:
   image: mariadb:10.4.1
   volumes:
    - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
   environment:
    TZ: "Asia/Bangkok"
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
    MYSQL_USER: 'user'
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'user'
    MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
 volumes:
  mariadb:
```

After setting up, I start my app and type an address `http://localhost:3000/login`. It gives me an error

```
The requested URL /login was not found on this server.
```

It works fine on XAMPP, but fail in docker.

Comment: Probably `mod_rewrite` missing? Enable it via `RUN a2enmod rewrite` in your Dockerfile. Also check that `AllowOverride` ist set.  Anyways, why do you need PHP & Maria for an React app?

Comment: I have added that in Dockerfile already.